# not getting relationships back in neo4j viz

Tags: neo4j

I'm using neo4j's built in viz tool but when I run a cypher query, I'm not getting back any relationships...

here is my cypher query:

```
$MATCH (n) WHERE n.Capability = 'Scoring' RETURN n
```

I do have relationships for those node properties but why aren't they showing?

EDIT:

here is some sample insert data...maybe its the way I'm inserting the data?

Nodes:

```
create (aa:TLA2 {AssetCategory: 'Service', Capability: 'Communications', ITDeliveryLead: 'person1', DeliveryMgr: 'person4'})
create (bb:TLA2 {AssetCategory: 'Service', Capability: 'Information Technology', ITDeliveryLead: 'person2', DeliveryMgr: 'person5'})
create (cc:TLA2 {AssetCategory: 'Application', Capability: 'Information Technology', ITDeliveryLead: 'person3', DeliveryMgr: 'person6'})
create (dd:TLA2 {AssetCategory: 'Service', Capability: 'Scoring', ITDeliveryLead: 'person8', DeliveryMgr: 'person9'})
```

Edges:

```
merge (aa) <- [:TALKSTO] - (dd)
merge (bb) <- [:TALKSTO] - (dd)
merge (cc) <- [:TALKSTO] - (dd)
```

when I create the edges...it doesn't link to the nodes for some reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not returned because you don't return any relationship.

In the browser you can just double click on a node in order to expand the relationships, or you can adapt the query to :

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-() WHERE n.Capability = 'Scoring' RETURN r, n
```

for returning them with Cypher

Comment: I got some of the relationshps back but not all of them...i got about 6 back but should have gotten about 20 back...why would that be? still doesn't seem like I'm getting all the nodes back either...

Comment: so the 20 relationships are connected to a node having Capability set to Scoring right ?

Comment: yep yep! sorry, I'm really new to this so still figuring this out...also, so one node may have a capability of scoring, but the related node may have another capability...

Comment: ok, change to `MATCH (n)-[r]-(b) WHERE n.Capability = 'Scoring' RETURN r, n, b`

Comment: hey Chris...still didn't work...maybe its the way I'm inserting the data? edited my question to reflect that